# React (Next) won't re-render after redux state change (yes, state returned as new object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I am facing a problem with **re-rendering** after a state change in my NextJS app.
The function `sendMessageForm` launches a redux action `sendMessage` which adds the message to the state.
The problem is unrelated to the returned state in the reducer as I am returning a new object(`return {...state}`) which should trigger the re-render!
Is there anything that might block the re-render ?
This is the file that calls & displays the state, so no other file should be responsible ! But if you believe the problem might lie somewhere else, please do mention !

```
import { AttachFile, InsertEmoticon, Mic, MoreVert } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Avatar, CircularProgress, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Message from '../../components/Message.component';
import styles from '../../styles/Chat.module.css'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux"
import * as chatActions from "../../state/action-creators/chatActions"

const Chat = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { roomId } = router.query

  const auth = useSelector((state)=> state.auth)
  const messages = useSelector((state)=> state.chat[roomId].messages)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const {getMessages, markAsRead, sendMessage} = bindActionCreators(chatActions, dispatch)

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
  

  const sendMessageForm = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log("***inputValue:", inputValue)

      sendMessage(roomId, inputValue)
  }

  const loadMessages = (page) => {
      if(roomId)
        getMessages(roomId, page)
  }

  //user-read-message
  useEffect(() => {
    //user-read-message
    markAsRead(roomId, auth.user._id)
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <Head>
            <title>Chat</title>
        </Head>

        <div className={styles.header}>
            <Avatar/>
            <div className={styles.headerInformation}>
                <h3>Zabre el Ayr</h3>
                <p>Last Seen ...</p>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.headerIcons}>
                <IconButton>
                    <AttachFile/>
                </IconButton>

                <IconButton>
                    <MoreVert/>
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.chatContainer}>
            <InfiniteScroll
                isReverse={true}
                pageStart={0}
                loadMore={loadMessages}
                hasMore={messages.hasNextPage || false}
                loader={<div className={styles.loader} key={0}><CircularProgress /></div>}
            >
                {Object.keys(messages.docs).map((key, index)=>{
                return<Message
                    key={index}
                    sentByMe={messages.docs[key].createdBy === auth.user._id}
                    message={messages.docs[key].msg}
                />})}
            </InfiniteScroll>
            <span className={styles.chatContainerEnd}></span>
        </div>

        <form className={styles.inputContainer}>
            <InsertEmoticon/>
            <input className={styles.chatInput} value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)}/>
            <button hidden disabled={!inputValue} type='submit' onClick={sendMessageForm}></button>
            <Mic/>
        </form>
    </div>)
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: is your store updating correctly? have you checked with redux web tools?

Comment: @coglialoro yes it is, I can see the new data perfectly using redux web tools and as I've mentioned to @kodamace, if I trigger a re-render (by typing in the form which uses `useState` hence re-rendering), the updated list will display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useSelector` requires a new object with a new reference from the object you are passing to it in order to trigger the re-render

What you're doing with `return {...state}` is just creating a new object for the parent object but not the nested one `useSelector` is using, which is in your case :

> const messages = useSelector((state)=> state.chat[roomId].messages)

So, you should return the whole state as a new object WITH a new `state.chat[roomId].messages` object

In other words, the references for the root object & the one being used should be changed.

Comment: I thought abt this but I was told that redux checks the root object for re-renders so i didn't bother testing it. I'll try this as soon as possible, fingers crossed :D